# No me funciona funcion CURDATE(),

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mariadb, gdb

Estoy intentando hacer funcionar esta función para sacar el ultimo día hace 3 meses, y no me funciona.

```
        SELECT (SUBDATE(ADDDATE
        (CURDATE()+INTERVAL 1 MONTH),
        INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())DAY)) 
        AS LastDayOfTheMonth;
```

ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION SQL1NORMALSTRINGS.ADDDATE does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Creo que es un problema de espacios, ¿sabéis como lo puedo arreglar?

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido al sitio ¿Qué motor de base de datos estás usando? ¿Puedes poner a qué te refieres con "el último día hace tres meses"? Incluye ejemplos, es decir si hoy es 20210609, ¿qué esperas que te devuelva exactamente la consulta?

Comment: uso mariadb, necesito el ultimo dia del mes de hace 3 meses, lo que pasa, es que me estoy preparando para un examen, y esto lo va a pedir, y no lo entiendo, porque la estructura es correcta. pero me da error, creo que es un problema de espacios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para MariaDB puedes obtener *el último día de hace tres meses* con la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH));
```

donde

[LAST_DAY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/last_day/) 
*Takes a date or datetime value and returns the corresponding value for the last day of the month*.
Toma un valor date o datetime y devuelve el valor correspondiente al último día del mes

[SUBDATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/subdate/) en este caso se comporta como un sinónimo para [DATE_SUB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_sub/) que se invoca `DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)` donde expr es una expresión numérica y unit indica la unidad temporal a substraer. En nuestro caso 3 y MONTH (meses), respectivamente.

Por último, para recuperar la fecha actual empleamos [SYSDATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sysdate/)

Como puedes comprobar por los enlaces, todas las funciones empleadas están definidas en MariaDB. La consulta ha sido probada [aquí](https://sqliteonline.com/).

No entiendo bien qué quieres conseguir con la consulta indicada en la pregunta original. No se ve por ningún lado el 3 correspondiente al número de meses hacia atrás que quieres conseguir, por ejemplo.